# Allow users to add bookmark/anchor on long pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm currently working on a Wordpress site with long scrolling pages of text. The client would prefer to NOT break it up into pages (yes, I know) so I'm trying to figure out if there's any way to allow logged in users to be able to save their place in the page so next time they log in, they can simply click a link and go back to where they left off?

I was thinking maybe a drag and drop 'add bookmark' type of thing, but I'm not sure that would work. Perhaps allowing the user to select part of the text and bookmark or highlight it that way.

I haven't yet tried anything because to be honest I don't know where to even start - and maybe it's a stupid idea anyhow. Any input would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a stupid idea, certainly. Any time you're actively thinking about the user experience on your site is time well spent, even if you then decide not to implement the feature - At least it's an active decision, not a passive one.

If you wanted to do something like that, I'd probably go with some sort of incrementally increasing <p> IDs, then either allow a drag and drop bookmark process, or even automatically keep a variable that records either the scroll position, or the ID of the topmost visible paragraph.

Something like (off the top of my head):

```
var curScrollPos
$('#wrapperdiv').scroll(function() {
    curScrollPos= $('#wrapperdiv').scrollTop();
});

// Wrapping the cookie write/save in setInterval so it's not continuously writing
setInterval(function() {
    // Save curPos here using method of your choice
}, 3000);
```

You could write a quick function that used curScrollPos to figure out which paragraph was at the top of the page by looking at their .top attribute, or whatever. (Although, that might get long/slow. Better to cache the list of .top values by adding each one to an array as you add the paragraph to the page)

Then on document load, just rewind them back to where they were before.

Comment: Probably I'd want the user to do their own bookmark - it would be less hassle. For me anyhow! Plus that way they could have more than one. Great idea with the paragraph IDs, thanks - here I was thinking I'd have to do a word count or character count or something ridiculous. And actually you reminded me of something I read once about paragraph permalinks, I believe that was doing the same sort of thing.

Comment: The easiest way for a user to do their own bookmark would be to forgo the drag-and-drop idea, then, and just add a second "click here to bookmark" type div to each paragraph that saves the paragraph ID to a cookie when clicked on.

Comment: ok so far I've got this jquery that adds a div before each paragraph, adds paragraph numbers and the same numbering scheme to the div. I can't add the code here because it won't let me use the enter key...